# Idris decision procedure type checking extremely slow, an inherent performance problem?

Tags: idris, dependent-type

```
decLte : (n : Nat) -> (m : Nat) -> Dec (LTE n m)
decLte Z _ = Yes LTEZero
decLte (S _) Z = No (\x => case x of LTEZero impossible ; LTESucc _ impossible)
decLte (S n) (S m) with (decLte n m)
  | Yes ltePrf = Yes (LTESucc ltePrf)
  | No lteContra = No (\(LTESucc p) => lteContra p)

data NatRange : Type where
   In : (l: Nat) -> (u: Nat) -> {auto yep : decLte l u = Yes _} -> NatRange

natRangeEx1 : NatRange
natRangeEx1 = In 500 2100
```

This code takes around 5 minutes to type check and uses >2GB of memory. I am stunned by the extremely poor performance. Can someone give me a good reason as in it's my code's problem or the Idris's inherent problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's Idris itself? My computer has frequently got frozen lastly (with an extremely high memory consumption) after I ran compilation of my code. I'm not really sure though, whether Idris itself is at fault or perhaps the Atom plugin I use. In my case, however, it happens rather randomly: sometimes the same code compiles quickly, another time it completely kills the machine…

Comment: I can confirm that this is very slow. Also changing to the builtin `isLTE` function does not make a difference. The reason is the `500` parameter. If it is changed to something closer to zero it is considerably faster. Unfortunately I was not able to compile the code using blodwen.

Comment: Indeed, I can now confirm too, that my problems are caused by Idris itself.